# Is a commit required after a backout method in mq?

Tags: ibm-mq, commit, backout

Firstly i am novice in MQ concepts and trying to understand things lately.

I know that backout method is used to rollback any uncommited transactions of puts or gets that have occurred within a unit of work since the last syncpoint.

My question here are:

1. The backout method , will it backout the message in backout queue immeadiately or after the backout count has reached ? ( I am guessing backout method and backout queues are related)
2. Do we have to call a commit after every backout method ?

Comment: It's not clear if you really intended to use the "was" tag (Windows Process Activation Service) or "websphere-mq" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The backout method , will it backout the message in backout queue
>   immeadiately or after the backout count has reached ? ( I am guessing
>   backout method and backout queues are related)

Immediate.  It returns the message to the original queue.  If your J2EE container has builtin support for backing out the message, then the logic will check the backout count and if it has been reached then the message will be put in the backout queue.

> Do we have to call a
>   commit after every backout method ?

No.